# Overlap Condition - Inside a Field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have a table like ***ID, IntrvalStartPoints, IntervalEndPoints***
Where StartPoints contains the start of intervals and the EndPoints is the end of the intervals.

For instance:

```
ID: 1000
StartPoints: 94994731,94997876,94998645,95001520,95005812,95007092, ENDPoints: 94996152,94998036,94998824,95001720,95005924,95007413,
```

Here we have 6 intervals <94994731,94996152>, <94997876,94998036>, ...

Can we write a query to check whether for example **ID:1000, Start:95005812, End:95005815** overlaps with any intervals or not.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the data types of these fields?

Comment: You need to normalize that table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT t.id, StartPoint, EndPoint, interval_start, interval_end
FROM (
  SELECT id, CAST(StartPoint AS INT64) StartPoint, CAST(EndPoint AS INT64) EndPoint
  FROM `project.dataset.intervals` t,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(StartPoints)) StartPoint WITH OFFSET pos1
  JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(EndPoints)) EndPoint WITH OFFSET pos2
  ON pos1 = pos2
) t
JOIN `project.dataset.checks` c ON c.id = t.id AND 
(interval_start BETWEEN StartPoint AND EndPoint 
OR interval_end BETWEEN StartPoint AND EndPoint)
```

you can test / play with it using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.intervals` AS (
  SELECT 1000 id, 
    '94994731,94997876,94998645,95001520,95005812,95007092' StartPoints,
    '94996152,94998036,94998824,95001720,95005924,95007413' EndPoints
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2000 id, 
    '74994731' StartPoints,
    '74996152' EndPoints
), `project.dataset.checks` AS (
  SELECT 1000 id, 95005812 interval_start, 95005815 interval_end
)
SELECT t.id, StartPoint, EndPoint, interval_start, interval_end
FROM (
  SELECT id, CAST(StartPoint AS INT64) StartPoint, CAST(EndPoint AS INT64) EndPoint
  FROM `project.dataset.intervals` t,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(StartPoints)) StartPoint WITH OFFSET pos1
  JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(EndPoints)) EndPoint WITH OFFSET pos2
  ON pos1 = pos2
) t
JOIN `project.dataset.checks` c ON c.id = t.id AND 
(interval_start BETWEEN StartPoint AND EndPoint 
OR interval_end BETWEEN StartPoint AND EndPoint)
```

with result as

```sql
Row id      StartPoint  EndPoint    interval_start  interval_end     
1   1000    95005812    95005924    95005812        95005815
```